# "I was intrigued about the event" Vs. "I was curious about the event"

Tags: difference

Are the words "[intrigued](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/intrigue?q=intrigued%20)" and "[curious](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/curious)" are simply synonyms or there are different uses for each one of them?

For example:

> "I was **intrigued about** the event yesterday morning."

Vs.

> "I was **curious** about the event yesterday morning."

By the definition of Cambridge dictionary it seems that to be "intrigued" is stronger than "curious". Isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

I believe "intrigued" is not followed by "about" but rather followed by "by" and "with."

On the other hand, "curious" is almost always followed by "about."

If you look carefully at these two, you'll realize that if you want to talk "about" something you should use the feeling of "curious" whereas you should use the feeling of "intrigued" when you talk about "an idea" or "an event."

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's still not understood, what is the actual deference between them. Do you want to say that I can't say "curious" about ideas or events?